# Open shift strange NPM issue - Module not found though installed

Tags: node.js, npm, openshift, xlsx

I am developing a node.js application and ran into a weird snag. I am developing on my mac then pushing my repo to my open shift gear. I push a few times a day and things have been going great until I added the XLSX module from npm. For some reason I am getting this error in open shift when my app tries to run:

```
Error: Cannot find module 'XLSX'
```

But what is strange is when i do `npm list` it shows that xlsx is indeed installed. I tried uninstalled and reinstalling the module but nothing seems to be working. Does anyone know why this might be happening?

Comment: To be clear, are you running `npm list` on the OpenShift server, or on your local machine?

Comment: from the OpenShift server

Answer (score 0):

So it automagically stopped with this error after multiple times of uninstalling the module and reinstalling, and restarting the app. I have no idea why it is suddenly working now because nothing of my code has changed and the module was installed before as it is now. Oh well!